# How do I force rpm -V to verify ALL files?

Tags: linux, rpm, verify

I want to be able to verify ALL files against the rpm database (all files originating from an rpm, that is).

Example: When I ask rpm to verify the package carrying /etc/hosts, I get:

```
# rpm -Vv setup-2.8.14-16.el6.noarch
.........  c /etc/aliases
S.5....T.  c /etc/bashrc
.........  c /etc/csh.cshrc
.........  c /etc/csh.login
.........  c /etc/environment
.........  c /etc/exports
.........  c /etc/filesystems
.........  c /etc/group
.........  c /etc/gshadow
.........  c /etc/host.conf
.........  c /etc/hosts
.........  c /etc/hosts.allow
(stuff deleted)
```

I want to see that e.g. /etc/hosts is changed. How do I do this?

Comment: IMHO should be http://unix.stackexchange.com/ (upvoting anyway since question looks ok).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An rpm spec file can explicitly say what aspects of a file should be verified by `-V`, and configuration files (shown by the `c` in the 2nd column of your output) are usually expected to be changed, and are not overridden on an update.

You can get the original file size and ownership fairly easily with `rpm -qlv`, so you can do an `ls` of the same files and then compare them. For example,

```
rpm=setup
rpm -ql $rpm | 
xargs ls -ld --time-style='+%b %d %Y' |
tr -s ' ' |
sort -k9 |
diff -u <(rpm -qlv $rpm |tr -s ' ' | sort -k9) -
```

can show changes (`-` prefix from rpm, `+` now) or not ( prefix).

---

Here's a script that takes a list of package names and uses `--dump` to get
the checksum info (etc), which on my Fedora 22 seems to be a sha256sum rather than
an md5sum, and compares it with the real file. Though `rpm -V` has an extra final field,
"capabilities differ", this info isn't provided in the dump output.

```
#!/bin/bash
for pkg
do rpm -q --dump "$pkg" |
 while read path size mtime digest mode owner group isconfig isdoc rdev symlink
 do if [ "$path" = package ] # not installed
    then echo "$path $size $mtime $digest $mode"
         continue
    fi
    S=. M=. F=. D=. L=. U=. G=. T=.
    type=$(stat --format='%F' $path)
    if [ "$type" = "regular file" ]
    then if realsum=$(sha256sum <$path)
         then [ $digest != ${realsum/ -/} ] && F=5
         else F=?
         fi
    elif [ "$type" = "symbolic link" ]
    then reallink=$(readlink $path)
        [ "$symlink" != "$reallink" ] && L=L
    # elif [ "$type" = "directory" ] ...
    fi
    eval $(stat --format='s=%s u=%U g=%G t=%Y hexmode=%f' $path)
    realmode=$(printf "%07o" 0x$hexmode)
    realmode6=$(printf "%06o" 0x$hexmode)
    [ "$mode" != "$realmode" -a "$mode" != "$realmode6" ] && M=M
    [ "$size" != "$s" ] && S=S
    [ "$owner" != "$u" ] && U=U
    [ "$owner" != "$g" ] && G=G
    [ "$mtime" != "$t" ] && T=T
    flags="$S$M$F$D$L$U$G$T"
    [ "$flags" = "........" ] ||
    echo "$flags $path" # missing: P capabilities
 done
done
```

Comment: I added a script to check the sum.

Comment: If I'd done that, I would (a) make it not bash-specific and (b) be inclined to reconstruct the report to make it look more like `rpm -V`.

Comment: it's now a bit more like `-V`.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be two questions:

- how to see if a particular file was modified
- how to check all packages.

For the first, you can ask `rpm` which package owns a file using the `-qf` options.  Assuming a POSIX shell, check `/etc/hosts`:

```
rpm -V $(rpm -qf /etc/hosts) | fgrep /etc/hosts
```

which of course can be made into a script, e.g.,

```
#!/bin/sh
rpm -V $(rpm -qf $1) | fgrep $1
```

To check all packages, use the `-a` option, e.g.,

```
rpm -Va
```

Replying to the clarification: the `c` that you see on the lines tells you that the file is marked with the rpm tag [`%config`](http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/~jw35/docs/rpm_config.html) tag.  This page lists the letters, including noting the use of `c`:

- [When Verification Fails — rpm -V Output](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-verify-output.html)

The RPM database only records the *original* size, md5sum, ownership of files.  The `%config` tag is a work-around used to acknowledge that some files are expected to be modified by the system maintainers (and to avoid cluttering the verification report).  You have a few choices (all involving extra work):

- you can download the binary rpm package, extract the files from it and diff them against the installed rpm
- you can record the original package contents (I use rcs locally for this sort of thing), and compare against the recorded version.

For extracting, the `unrpm` script is useful.  (There is more than one with this name; [here is a link](https://casper.berkeley.edu/svn/trunk/roach/sw/busybox-1.10.1/examples/unrpm) to one).

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question was unclear. My situation is that I know that a file (e.g. /etc/hosts) is changed. When I run rpm -Vv there is no "5" in the result for the file. I suppose that the md5 check is not executed on /etc/hosts at all. I want to run the rpm verification in a way, so that the md5 check is executed for ALL files (including e.g. /etc/hosts) and I want to see the result showing "5" for ALL files that are changed ... including files like /etc/hosts.
(hope this is more clear)